# foreach array that has array inside in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am sure is easy but I can't figure it out!

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#354 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_user"]=>
    int(1)
    ["DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"]=>
    string(10) "2020-04-09"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Prueba del dia 9"
    ["description"]=>
    string(28) "Prueba del dia 9 descripcion"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Pinazo"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(4) "Guna"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#351 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_user"]=>
    int(1)
    ["DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"]=>
    string(10) "2020-04-09"
    ["title"]=>
    string(17) "Prueba del dia 92"
    ["description"]=>
    string(29) "Prueba del dia 92 descripcion"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Pinazo"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(4) "Guna"
  }
}
```

I want to do a foreach and get all the values from each object.

```
 @foreach($preguntas as $pregunta)
nvalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I am doing this and it doesn't work.

This is the code in the php

```
$preguntas = Question::select('questions.id', 'questions.id_user', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
->whereRaw("DATE(questions.date) = CURDATE()")
->get()
->skip($saltar)
->take($cantidad)
->toJson();

    return view('preguntasRespuestas')->with('preguntas', json_decode($preguntas));
```

Thank you for your time!
  I return preguntas to the view preguntasRespuestas

Comment: plz post your code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this? you do not need to do tojson and decode json, laravel does it for you.

```php
$preguntas = Question::select('questions.id', 'questions.id_user', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
->whereRaw("DATE(questions.date) = CURDATE()")
->get()
->skip($saltar)
->take($cantidad)
->all();

    return view('preguntasRespuestas')->with('preguntas', $preguntas);
```

Comment: I did it and it doesn't enter into the foreach

Comment: @PacoPinazoGuna what do  you mean it doesn't enter into the foreach?

Comment: @PacoPinazoGuna is `$preguntas` the data you posted?

Comment: Yes! It throws argument invalid

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets say it is like this:

```
$first = '{"id":1,"title":"Prueba del dia 1","description":"Prueba del dia 1 descripcion"}';
$second = '{"id":2,"title":"Prueba del dia 2","description":"Prueba del dia 2 descripcion"}';
```

So $perguntas would look like this:

```
$perguntas = 
[
    json_decode($first),
    json_decode($second)
];
```

And foreach:

```
foreach($perguntas as $perg) {
print_r($perg->id);
echo "<br>";
print_r($perg->title);
echo "<br>";
print_r($perg->description);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}
```

Result:

```
1
Prueba del dia 1
Prueba del dia 1 descripcion

2
Prueba del dia 2
Prueba del dia 2 descripcion
```

Also with your query you are returning an object, not an array, so either you later cast it as array `(array)$perguntas` or:

```
$preguntas = Question::select('questions.id', 'questions.id_user', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
->whereRaw("DATE(questions.date) = CURDATE()")
->get()
->skip($saltar)
->take($cantidad)
->toJson();

    return view('preguntasRespuestas')->with('preguntas', json_decode($preguntas, true));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But laravel throws invalid argument foreach(). I don't know how to do the foreach